# Javascript for statement Keeps Showing undefined

Tags: javascript

So i made this cracker/bruteforce just to learn / test nuthin illegal here since am doing it via localhost and my own php login.

So am keep getting Failed:undefined:undefined

When its suppose to be this Failed:user:pass

Any help?

Thanks

```
<script>

function crack() {

    var cracked_area = document.getElementById("cracked_acc");
    var failed_area = document.getElementById("failed_acc");

    var num_users = 0;
    var num_cracked = 0;

    var html_next;

    var user_l = document.getElementById("users");
    var pass_l = document.getElementById("pass");

    if (user_l.value == "") {
        alert("The username field cant be empty!")
    } else if (pass_l.value == "") {
        alert("The password field cant be empty!")
    }

    var message = document.getElementById('message');

    var user_l_s = user_l.value.split("\n");
    var pass_l_s = pass_l.value.split("\n");


    for (var i = 0; i < user_l_s.length; i++) {
        num_users++;
        for (var j = 0; j < pass_l_s.length; j++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/postdata.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {'user': user_l_s[i], 'pass': pass_l_s[j]},
                dataType: 'text',

                success: function (response) {
                    html_next = response;

                    if (html_next.indexOf("Failed") > -1) {
                        failed_area.value += 'Failed:' + user_l_s[i] + ':' + pass_l_s[j] + '\n';
                    } else if (html_next.indexOf("Cracked") > -1) {
                        num_cracked++;
                        cracked_area.value += 'Cracked:' + user_l_s[i] + ':' + pass_l_s[j] + '\n';
                    }

                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    message.innerHTML = "Loading results...";
                }
            });
        }
        message.innerHTML = "Total Accounts Cracked:" + num_cracked + "/" + num_users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `success`-callback you refer to the variable `i`.
But think about what happens when the for-loop runs. The loop is already finished when the callback is called and thats why `i` equals `pass_l_s.length` and therefore `user_l_s[i]` is undefined.
When you want to use the variable `i` in a callback you have to create your little own world with a local `i`

```
success: (function(i){

    return function (response) {
        html_next = response;

        if (html_next.indexOf("Failed") > -1) {
            failed_area.value += 'Failed:' + user_l_s[i] + ':' + pass_l_s[j] + '\n';
        } else if (html_next.indexOf("Cracked") > -1) {
            num_cracked++;
            cracked_area.value += 'Cracked:' + user_l_s[i] + ':' + pass_l_s[j] + '\n';
        }
    }
})(i)
```

We defined a self-invoking function here which expects the parameter `i`. When the for-loop now loop through all `i` everytime a new function is returned from the self-invoking function which now has access to `i` cause its locally defined as parameter of the self-invoking function.

**Good to know**
Javascript1.7 introduces a new keyword `let` which serves for exactly that purpose. But at these days its not usable in production

Comment: Thank you for the info and answering a perfect answer marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you call the `ajax()` function within the loop. It's asynchronous call made in a loop statement and by the time the response arrives back to the client the loop is already over and hence the `user_l_s[i]` will be undefined. Change the response format to return which user has failed to login.